# What is the difference between Inter-process Communication and communicating between executables?

Tags: ipc, exe, inter-process-communicat

> Inter-process communication (IPC) is communication between two executable files.

Why can't we mention communication between `exe` files? Why inter-process communication?

Can both terms be used interchangeably?  If yes/no please explain with reason.

Answer (score 3):

Saying that two exe files communicate is technically incorrect, since file is a set of bytes on the hard drive. Therefore, two files (sets of bytes) cannot really communicate. Process, on the other hand, is an operating system term , which means instance of program running ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))). The sentence you've cited is probably intended to explain IPC to someone not familiar with operating systems design and it's an attempt to simplify.